# How can I change the "Database Name" in AWS RDS for Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I wanted to create a replicate of my production database for staging and created the staging DB instance from a production snapshot.  However, this new instance still has the Database Name: "production-database".  I was able to rename the database on PSQl to "staging-databse," but this is not reflected in the AWS Console. I'm afraid that future developers will be very confused, and was wonderign how to rename the "Database Name" on AWS?

Comment: I'd recommend not using automatic database creation from console. It's better to login just after creating to a standard `postgres` database and use `create database dbname`. This won't help you in this issue though.

Comment: How do you login though? If DB is private and not accessible from outside of VPC

Comment: This is latest, but check if your db instance is eligible for what you are trying to achieve using Amazon RDS Blue/Green Deployments: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-overview.html

Answer (score 39):

Not immediately obvious - when creating a new db expand the Additional Configuration card to create an initial db name

[image: Addtional Configuration]

Comment: This is stupid!

Comment: you're kidding me right, I had to delete and recreate the DB,...

Comment: we all have to come here at some point, tbh ! hahaha like i am doing today. for sth so important as Initial DB Name, how they decided to put that on the dead end of the config process. tf!!

Comment: This is ridiculous, you saved me here but could not believe this when I saw it.

Comment: Indeed me too, didn't see how to fix this in the documentation. Glad I saw this post

Answer (score 31):

I created a new free tier instance for small scale testing and this is the DB name I see in my configuration:

[image]

I looked everywhere, but could not figure out what my database name is or how to create an initial database. Turns out the database name is `postgres`. It's also worth noting that I kept the default username, so in this case the username and database name are the same. If you changed the default username and `postgres` isn't working, maybe try using your username as your database name.

Comment: Great point about the free tier. It looks like you may not have an option to change the name. The line shown in @nakulthebuilder's answer doesn't exist for my free tier db.

Answer (score 25):

Don't use the default database option.  All it does is create a custom-named database by default.  There may be uses for it, but I never use it, because it seems to serve no purpose at all other than to specify what the database that's created by default (when the instance is first created) will be named.

> **Database Name**
>
> If you want to specify a database name for the default database, type a name for your database of up to 63 alpha-numeric characters. If you do not provide a name, the default "postgres" database is created.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_CreatePostgreSQLInstance.html

I assume this is intended to be a convenience for new RDS users, but to me, it seems unnecessary.  It has no apparent impact on ongoing operation of the instance, which can, of course, have multiple independent databases on it.

This apparently can't subsequently be changed, so it's more of an annoyance than anything.  I always leave this blank.

Comment: so what is the default database name then? I forgot what I set mine too and RDS panel won't let me see it.

Comment: Log into the actual database instance you created.  If you didn't specify one, there should be one called "postgres" but you can create whatever you want, once you've logged in.

Comment: I found the DB name in the Configuration tab of my database cluster in the web console.

Comment: I don't see any DB name in the config tab.

Comment: Has anyone seen it? still cant find it neither @RyanR in the config I cant even see cluster

Answer (score 1):

look on the configuration tab of the writer.

Comment: Although this doesn't answer the question as asked by the OP, it certainly appears to be correct information for Amazon Aurora. i.e. Configuration tab of the writer instance in the cluster, not configuration tab of the cluster.