# How to connect to PostgreSQL DB without a "database" name from AWS RDS

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Using the node pg package, `pg`, I'm trying to connect to a PostgreSQL DB created in AWS-RDS. I believe the DB was NOT given a name when creating an instance, note that an instance is different than a DB. When trying to connect using `Client` or `Pool` from `pg` my syntax is

```
const client = new Client({
  host     : <<RDS ENDPOINT>>,
  user     : <<RDS DB USERNAME>>,
  password : <<RDS DB PASSWORD>>,
  port     : <<RDS DB PORT>>
});
client.connect()
  .then(data => {
    console.log('connected');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

But every time I am returned with `error: database <<linux user name>> does not exist`.

Now creating a different PostgreSQL instance and supplying a name for the DB I am able to add a `database` prop to my `Client` objects config and everything works and I am returned with a console log of `connected`.

So my question is, how am I supposed to connect to the DB on AWS-RDS without supplying a `database` prop in my `Client` config?

## Edits

### edit 1

Supplying a `database` prop with an empty string will be overwritten with my linux username

Comment: When you create a Postgres DB it says under `Additional configuration > Database options > Initial database name`: *"If you do not specify a database name, Amazon RDS does not create a database."* Some clients may not be able to connect without a database.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With the `node-postgres` package you need to supply a database prop in your Client/Pool config object. If your PostgreSQL DB does not have a name, say if you created it using AWS-RDS then this DB NAME will default to `postgres`. Simply supplying the database prop with `postgres` should solve any problems you have with an un-named DB.

```
const client = new Client({
  host     : <<RDS ENDPOINT>>,
  user     : <<RDS DB USERNAME>>,
  password : <<RDS DB PASSWORD>>,
  port     : <<RDS DB PORT>>,
  database : 'postgres' // supplying a database name with `postgres`

});
```

Comment: Took me a long time to figure out. It was also mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43099155/how-can-i-change-the-database-name-in-aws-rds-for-postgresql but could not locate in the official documentation.